# I need help figuring out why I'm getting NaN in this function

Tags: javascript, nan

```js
function multipleLetterCount(str){
  var finalObj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(!str[i] in finalObj){
        finalObj[str[i]] = 1;
    } else {
        finalObj[str[i]]++;
    }
}
return finalObj;
}

console.log(multipleLetterCount("SomeWord"));
```

I need help figuring out why the values are coming up as NaN. Thanks

Comment: Because `!str[i] in finalObj` is the same as `(!str[i]) in finalObj`.

Comment: change `(!str[i] in finalObj)` to `(!(str[i] in finalObj))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why the values are coming up as NaN

`str[i]` represents different character in each iteration. When you negate that character like `!str[i]` that becomes `false`. Hence the condition (`if(false in finalObj)`) is always `false` and executes only the `else` part. At this point `finalObj[str[i]]` is `undefined`. Finally, incrementing `undefined` (`undefined++`) gives you `NaN`.

Try with [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) which returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property:

```js
function multipleLetterCount(str){
  var finalObj = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(!finalObj.hasOwnProperty(str[i])){
        finalObj[str[i]] = 1;
    } else {
        finalObj[str[i]]++;
    }
  }
  return finalObj;
}

console.log(multipleLetterCount("SomeWord"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code like this

```js
function multipleLetterCount(str){
var finalObj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     if (finalObj[str[i]]) {
     finalObj[str[i]]++;
     } else {
     finalObj[str[i]] = 1;
     }
}
return finalObj;
}

console.log(multipleLetterCount("SomeWord"));
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this way, it isn't very forward compatible (what if `finalObj[str[i]] == 0`)

Comment: It just checks whether the property already exists. It will return false if it is undefined. `{}` will return false since the property does not exist there.

Comment: It will return false if it is undefined, false, null, 0... (many falsey values) In this case, I don't recommend it due to the `0` false-ness

Comment: @Joven28 Nope, it will return false for other things, like `0`, as commented above.

Comment: I know that false == 0. But since the property has an initial value of 1 there's no way that it will encounter finalObj[str[i]] == 0. Can you explain why is it possible to encounter finalObj[str[i]] == 0?. Sorry I just can't understand it :)

Comment: @Joven28 because someone with a similar problem may have the condition where it equals 0, or maybe Adrian tweaks his code a bit to initialise it to 0. Your code is correct, just not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are a plethora of ways to resolve the problem, all of which depend on how robust you need your function to be.

For simplicity, instead of `if(!str[i] in finalObj)`, do `if (!(str[i] in finalObj))`.

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```js
let string = 'SomeWord';

const result = string.split('').reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b] ? a[b]++ : a[b] = 1
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```